# Concat multiple columns with filter in QueryRecord (NiFi)

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a JSON looks like:

```
[ {
  "metric_name" : "ga:bounces",
  "metric_value" : "16",
  "report_date" : "20210625",
  "utm_campaign" : "retail_group",
  "utm_source" : "(direct)",
  "utm_content" : "(not set)",
  "utm_term" : "(not set)",
  "utm_medium" : "search"
}, {
  "metric_name" : "ga:sessionDuration",
  "metric_value" : "1576.0",
  "report_date" : "20210625",
  "utm_campaign" : "rb_olv",
  "utm_source" : "google",
  "utm_content" : "(not set)",
  "utm_term" : "(not set)",
  "utm_medium" : "cpc"
}]
```

What I want:

```
[ {
  "metric_name" : "ga:bounces",
  "metric_value" : "16",
  "report_date" : "20210625",
  "utm_marks" : "utm_campaign=retail_group&utm_medium=search"
}, {
  "metric_name" : "ga:sessionDuration",
  "metric_value" : "1576.0",
  "report_date" : "20210625",
  "utm_marks" : "utm_campaign=rb_olv&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc"
}]
```

If some of utm values are inside `()` I should ignore it (key + value), it can be `(none)`, `(direct)`, `(not provided)`, `(not set)`

I tried with `QueryRecord`:

```
SELECT 
metric_name,
metric_value,
'utm_campaign=' || utm_campaign || '&utm_source=' || utm_source || '&utm_medium=' || utm_medium || '&utm_term=' || utm_term || '&utm_content=' || utm_content as utm_marks
FROM FLOWFILE
```

But it will not truncate values like `(none)`, `(direct)`. How can I improve statement?

Answer (score 1):

QueryRecord uses Apache Calcite for SQL parsing/evaluation, take a look at their CASE statement, you might be able to do something like `CASE WHEN utm_source != '(not set)' THEN '&utm_source=' || utm_source ELSE '' END`